# Javascript alert message not showing up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, updatepanel

I have a page written in asp.net, in which I am calling Javascript alert message and it is not showing up, if I clear cache memory of browser then the alert message is showing up.

Can anybody tell the reason and solution?

Comment: can you please paste your code what you have done so far ?

Comment: it is simply an alert box which is validating fileds. calling on submit button click.

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me is there any affect of cache memory on javascript alert message ?

Comment: I do not think so there is any affect of cache memory on alert message, Java Script interpreter has no idea which variable is required by the inner function.

Comment: i guess you are using update panel?paste your markup code so can say what exactly problem is

Comment: Actually i am calling javascript method from pop up page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onClientClick` like this

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_click()" OnClientClick="return check()"    
     runat="server"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit ?')) {
          // do further form validation here..  
          return true;

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
```